# after going on specific page through deep link URL when pressed back it get disabled the back pop for app as well as device

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-links, flutter-deep-link

> as I am using deep link  URLS for opening different activity of my app but on expected activity launch it get disable the back button for device as well as for my app bar back pressed so I cant come back to Home page what I am doing wrong. i have tried for all launch mode is singleTask, singletop, singleInstance,standard.

back button getting disabled on opening flutter app specific activity through deep links URLs. I am expecting when I pressed the back button its Homepage should appear.